# Element Size Based on Monitor Width

Tags: html, css, width

I am creating my own personal website as a test for what I have learned so far in HTML and JavaScript. I made the toolbar, and it looks nice on my monitor, which has quite a large width. I have the toolbar contents to be in the center. I tried accessing it on a smaller monitor, and the elements in the toolbar overlapped each other because I set the contents based on percentages. I know that measuring with pixels will come up with the same problem. How would I create a website where if the monitor width is larger than x pixels, then it will center the contents of the toolbar, but if the monitor width is smaller than x pixels, it will not center the contents of the toolbar?

As you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EnHEr/) jsFiddle, the elements overlap, but if you drag the view pane wider, you can see that it centers.

index.html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="links">
            <ol>
                <li id="home"><a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li id="blog"><a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/blog/index.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li id="forum"><a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/forum/index.html">Forums</a></li>
                <li id="chatbox"><a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/chatbox/index.html">Chatbox</a></li>
                <li id="code"><a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/code/index.html">Code</a></li>
                <li id="calendar"><a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/calendar/index.html">Calendar</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div id="login">
            Username: <input type="text" name="firstname"></input>
            Password: <input type="text" name="lastname"></input>
            <a href="justinpchang.zxq.net/user/loginlanding.html"><button id="submit" class="button">Submit</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background-color:#EBF2F0;
margin-top:50px;
}
#links{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
top:-10px;
position:absolute;
vertical-align: center;
}
a:link{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFF00;
}
a:visited{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFF00;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#000BF2;
}
a:active{
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFF00;
}
li{
display:inline;
padding:0px;
font-family:Courier;
}
ol{
list-style-type: none;
}
#header{
width:100%;
padding:5px 10px;
margin:0px;
height:25px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;
background-color:#000000;   
}
#toolbar{
width:70%;
margin-left:15%;
margin-right:15%;
}
#home,#blog,#forum,#chatbox,#code,#calendar{
padding:10px;
color:#000BF2;
}
#home:hover,#blog:hover,#forum:hover,#chatbox:hover,#code:hover,#calendar:hover{
background-color:#2E2E2D;
color:#000BF2;
}
#login{
color:#FFFFFF;
margin-right:30px;
text-align:right;
}
#submit{
margin-top:-7px;
margin-left:10px;
padding:6px;
}
```

Comment: You need to make your `#header` width bigger, have the login drop down on click/hover, or make your elements smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a CSS only solution you could play with `min-width`:

```
#toolbar{
  width:70%;
  margin-left:15%;
  margin-right:15%;
  min-width:1200px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EnHEr/1/)