# 100% width unless that's smaller than x, then fixed

Tags: css

I have a site using 100% width header navigation, but fixed 960px content.

Thus, there's horizontal scroll when browser resized to <960px - but the header/nav stops, while the content continues beneath.

How can I specify that:

```
width: 100%;
```

should be:

```
//IF 100pcwidth < 960px:
width: 960px;
//ELSE:
width: 100%;
```

I assume I need to use JS somehow to detect the screen width, and do something.. but I've never really learnt JS, just the basics to implement sample code, and make minor adjustments.

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: see [`max-width`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/)...

Comment: `min-width` seems just what I need! Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed, now that you've changed your example, it should be `min-width`.

Comment: Does this help?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529587/html-element-size-based-on-monitor-width][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529587/html-element-size-based-on-monitor-width

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I thought you were just linking me to the page (it mentions min too). Mark's answer in conjunction made me realise that I screwed up my example..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.example{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I screwed up my example, but `min-width` is perfect! Thanks.